# want to get not Deferred object but array

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I want to get tweets by code `twitter.tweets()`, but **ajax method** of class `Twitter` returns only **Deferred object** such as shown bottom of this question.

```
class Twitter
  tweets = []

  getTweets: ->
    tweets_array = []
    $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&rpp=100&q=%40weed_7777')
    .done((data) =>
      $.each data.results, (i, item) ->
        tweets_array.push item.text
      @tweets = tweets_array
    )

twitter = new Twitter

###
Present Code
###
twitter.getTweets()
.done ->
  console.log twitter.tweets

###
Ideal Code ... very simple !
###
console.log twitter.tweets()
```

[image]

Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: doubt you want that! you shouldn't block code execution waiting for an asynchronous call to come back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with Javascript you should be highly aware of the fact that you are working in an asynchronous/evented environment. So in the end you will be forced to get used to this. Of course there are some strategies to make life easier for example by using the async library (https://github.com/caolan/async)

```
async.series [
    (callback) => 
        $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/search').done (data) => 
            @tweets = (item for item in data)
            callback(null, pass_some_data_if_you_want)
    ,
    (callback) =>
        $.getJSON('http://search.twitter.com/some_other_search').done (data) => 
            do_what_ever_you_want_and_need()
            callback(null, pass_some_data_if_you_want)
    ],
    (error, result) => handle_error_case(error)
```

Obviously this makes only sense if you multiple actions that you want to execute in series.
If you just have one. than your code

```
twitter.getTweets().done -> console.log twitter.tweets
```

is the best way to go.

Comment: you should pass some falsey value to the callback as first argument to indicate that there's no error, i.e. `callback null, pass_some_data_if_you_want`